# Listing ALL logged-in users. Also the ones not using a shell

Tags: ssh, users

We are working with an application that logs in to a Linux server (Ubuntu server 14.04) and just requests a reverse tunnel.

Before we did this with Plink. And when the client was running Plink, I was able to list the users who were logged in with the `who` command. The `who` command only shows users who opened a shell. So with the new application the logged-in users do not show up when the who command is entered.

With Netstat you CAN find out which users are logged in because the entry is like:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5941            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1009       75337       25629/sshd: <USER>
```

Is there a command which generates a list of ALL users logged in, because you can clearly see that the system knows that it is running an SSH session with a certain user.